# Ubuntu 18 VS Code error Enoent: no such directory, lstat'/snap/code'

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error in VSCode after the latest update of VSCode.
This happens in Version: 1.30.0.

I think VSCode is looking for wrong directory, 
the actual VSCode directory is : '~/snap/code/'
not in '/snap/code/'

any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm the same happening to me

Comment: I confirm the bug

Comment: Please wait for the new release

Answer (score 10):

Not a fix, but a workaround:

```
sudo ln --symbolic /snap/vscode /snap/code
```

It might be noteworthy that my snaps are in /snap, not ~/snap.  You may need to adjust if yours are in your home directory.

Comment: I also have it in `~/snap` and symbolic link to `~/snap/code` already exists, but it doesn't work as expected. Still.